# Teradata: move data from one server to another

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two servers.

Is there a way to move data from one server to the other as a MERGE?
From here it seems like that this is [not possible](http://forums.teradata.com/forum/database/how-to-fetch-the-data-from-one-server-and-insert-in-to-other-server-in-sql-assistance) and it seems that the only available option is [fastload](http://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_13_10/index.html#page/Load_and_Unload_Utilities/B035_2411_020A/2411Ch01.03.02.html#ww1841331)

Has something changed since 2009?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the individual utilities, look into MultiLoad.  It supports UPSERT operations.
Or, if you have TPT available, it helps to simplify getting the data off of the source server and then into the target server (using the UPDATE).

Answer (score 0):

Using Teradata Parallel Transporter (TPT) you can move the data between systems using a named pipe without having to land the data on disk as an intermediate step. There is an [article](http://developer.teradata.com/tools/articles/use-teradata-parallel-transporter-to-move-data-without-landing-the-data-to-disk) on the Teradata Developer Exchange that explains the process with an example.